# How to use openquery in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, openquery

I have to pass parameters to a linked server and I have to use open query, I have a code as below:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)

SELECT @VAR = 'CA'

SELECT @TSQL = 'SELECT * INTO newtable FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Now I need to use it in a stored procedure but I get an ambiguous syntax error. How I can use it in a stored procedure?

Comment: Why you're using a dynamic SQL? Why not just `SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = '+ QUOTENAME(@Var, '''') + '');`

Comment: becouse instead of pubs.dbo.authors, I use a function such as:  authors ( null , ''''' + @ToDate + ''''' , null, null,null,null,null, null ,null,null,null,null,null,3, null )

Comment: Post the complete error message - all of it. And you can't debug the dynamic sql your code creates without seeing what it created, can you? So post the contents of `@TSQL` and examine it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Name]

AS

DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)
SET @VAR = 'CA'

SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * INTO newtable FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ' + @VAR + ' '')'

EXEC (@TSQL)
```